# Php form not sending email on different server

Tags: php, html, forms

Im using contact form and it worked since now. After clicking "send" I have confirm message and nothing happens. The webmaster mail `"test@gmail.com"` is an example.

This the code:

```
    <?php
    ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8'); 
    /* Subject and Email Variables */

$emailSubject = 'Wiadomosc z Formularza Kontaktowego ze strony WWW';
$webMaster = 'test@gmail.com';
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    /* Gathering Data Variables*/

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $topic = $_POST['topic'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];

    if (empty($_POST['email']))
    {
    echo 'error';
    exit;
    }
    if (empty($_POST['phone']))
    {
    echo 'error';
    exit;
    }
    if (empty($_POST['name']))
    {
    echo 'error';
    exit;
    }
    if (empty($_POST['text']))
    {
    echo 'error';
    exit;
    }

$body = <<<EOD

    Imię i Nazwisko: $name <br />
    Organizacja/Firma: $company <br />
    Numer telefonu: $phone <br />
    Email: $email <br />
    Temat: $topic <br />
    Wiadomość: $text <br />
    EOD;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

/* Results rendered as HTML */

$theResults = <<<EOD
OK




   EOD;
   echo $theResults;
   ?>
```

is it the server? or maybe something is missing me?

Comment: Adding data from the form directly to the header without further checking is a really bad idea, because someone could find a way to use it to deliver spam. Did you change anything? If not then probably you already where used to send spam and your server was blacklisted or the receiving mail server started to do SPF checks. But there could also be other reasons (e.g. your hoster stopped to support sending mails via `mail`)

Answer (score 0):

You should check what `mail()` function returns, print out `$success`

```
var_dump($success);
die;
```

see if it's true or false, if it's true and you are not getting the email, then probably it's something wrong on the server, then that's a different issue and needs a trouble shooting on the server you use.